# Is this a case of builder pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I am developing a simple ticket management system. When a ticket is created i have to perform 4-5 operations sequentially. Below is my code

```
pubic ActionResult CreateTicket(Ticket ticket)
{
    TicketRepository ts = new TicketRepository();

    if(ts.CreateTicket(ticket))
    {
        INotification emailNotification = new Email();
        emailNotification.SendTicketAlert();

        IResponsible assignToUser = new AssignToUser();
        assignToUser.assign();

        DummyObj obj = new DummyObj();
        obj.someDummyOperation();
    }
}
```

Do you think this is the case of builder pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, since one of the points of the builder pattern is to do away with the awkwardness that comes from having a class that has many configuration options when instantiated:

```
class MyClass {

    public MyClass(Object option1, Object option2, Object option3, ...Object option15){...};

}
```

This immediately leads to awkwardness when constructing an instance:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(o, null, null, o1, null, null, o2...);
```

The anti-pattern solution is to create many, many constructors to handle the most likely configuration options required by the client:

```
class MyClass {

    public MyClass(Object option1){...};
    public MyClass(Object option2, Object3){...};
    public MyClass(Object option1, Object option2, Object option3){...};
    .
    .
    .

}
```

If you were to implement the builder pattern you'd do something like this:

```
var myClass = CreateMyClass().option1().option15().build();
```

With the final call returning an instance of the class.  This is a fair amount of stage machinery to build, but it might be worth it in code that is consumed by other code.

As an aside this pattern is less needed in languages that have named parameters where you can do things like

```
new MyClass(option15=o);
```

Comment: ts.CreateTicket() simply inserts a ticket in database. This code is just a dummy which i have posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Builder is categorized as [creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Creational).  Since you are not creating a complex object, your code cannot be considered to be using Builder.

If you really want to use a pattern, you should take a look at [Chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern which seems more apt for what you are trying to do.